# Reading data in grid view c#

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I am tring to read data from an excel file to a `DataGridView` using C#. My data in excel is 1.001. However, `DataGridView` is fetching it as 1.0009999999. Please help me out how I could resolve it and display 1.001 in my `DataGridView`.

Comment: What is your column type?

Answer (score 0):

Given your column type is correctly set to `float` or `double`:

```
dataGridView.Columns["ColumnName"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N3";
```

What you're seeing is the inability of a base 2 floating point number being unable to accurately represent a base 10 number, I presume.

Alternatively you can just try using `decimal` instead.  This is a base 10 floating point number.

Comment: Cannot change my column type to decimal or float bcz i do have some values in same column as string

Comment: @Nishant then when you're generating the string to input into the `DataGridView` format the number first: `myNumber.ToString("N3")`

Comment: It is not allowing me to use (“N3”) showing error “represent text as sequence of utf-16 code” where as the variable in which i am reading value id of STRING TYPE and more over when the value is being read by data table it is reading 1.001 as 1.000999 and when I am using is exponential format then also 1.001 is not catched by this if condition where as 0.001 is catched in if exponential block